I am automating makemytrip.com in selenium python,I want to click on each navigation tab one by one,not working with the below code
Code:
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")
navigations = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="SW"\]/div\[1\]/div\     [2\]/div/div/nav/ul/li/span/a')
numberofpages = len(navigations)
print(numberofpages)
navigation1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="SW"\]/div\[1\]/div\   [2\]/div/div/nav/ul/li/span/a/span\[2\]\['+str(numberofpages)+'\]').text
print(navigation1)
for i in range(0,int(navigation1)):
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="SW"\]/div\[1\]/div\[2\]/div/div/nav/ul/li/span/a/span\[2\]\   ["+str(i)+"\]"').click()


This might help you -
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Assuming you have initialized the webdriver already, if not, do it like this:
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or whichever webdriver you are using

driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/")

# Finding the navigation tabs
navigations = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="makeFlex font12"]/div/div/nav/ul/li/a/span')

# Getting the number of navigation tabs
number_of_pages = len(navigations)
print("Number of navigation tabs:", number_of_pages)

# Iterating through each navigation tab
for i in range(number_of_pages):
    navigations[i].click()

Make sure you have the necessary imports (webdriver and By). Also, ensure that your WebDriver is correctly set up and compatible with your browser.

its not working, not clicking on each page, its only clicking on first page
